# Trying to make java application (Executable Jar) that uses OpenCV portable. Getting unsatisfied link error

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have made a application to grab video from a webcam and detect motion using OpenCV and JavaCV. I am trying to export as an executable jar using eclipse. The program runs fine in eclipse as does the exe jar on the computer I coded the program on.

What I am trying to accomplish is to make the exe Jar run on computers that don't have OpenCV installed. Basically what I would consider a portable application. When I run the exe jar on a different computer that has nothing installed other than the JRE I get unsatisfied link errors seen below.

```
Exception in thread "Video Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\JohnD\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp91062429652918\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:566)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.start(OpenCVFrameGrabber.java:174)
    at VideoPanel.run(VideoPanel.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_core244 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:481)
    ... 13 more
```

I have looked for a solution to what I am doing wrong. Most of the topics I have come across with unsatisfied link errors like the ones I am receiving have been trying to get it to run the first time through within there IDE, which is not the case here. I would think my dependencies are correct in the libraries in the build path since I can get it to run perfectly when I am on the computer that has everything installed but I still believe I am doing something wrong with the build.

Again I am trying to make it so the Jar can run on computers where OpenCV/JavaCV is not installed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `opencv` is not installed in the target machine, than you need to deliver the necessary opencv's dll file and set the corresponding library path, `opencv` is a precondition of `javacv`

for example:

```
jar yourapp.jar -Djava.library.path="/path/to/OpenCV/library"
```

[also check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308836/1225337)