# NO opencv_java300 in java.library.path

Tags: java, opencv, jar

Thanks in advance..

I have a project that uses **opencv-300.jar** as external library. I have tried this in eclipse and in **natBeans.** In both it is working successfully when I am running my project from IDE itself. 
I want my project to export it as a runnable (or executable) jar. 
I placed my **opencv_java300.dll** file in source folder with main java file and given its name in

```
 System.loadLibrary("opencv_java300");
```

I placed opencv-300.jar in external jar libraries and all other files which are needed in Main program. it is working successfully when running from IDE but when I am creating executable jar, it shows an error

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no     
   opencv_java300 in
   java.library.path
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
   at CropFaceImage.main(CropFaceImage.java:27)
```

Please tell me Is there any way to give **java.library.path** in program itself. My project is working sucsessfully even when I have removed path for **opencv_java300.dll** file in external library.

Comment: For mac see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35112123/1924979

Comment: Useful answer is here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/2309723/1979882

Comment: In my case I used https://github.com/openpnp/opencv and had to put `nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();` at the beginning of my code to use the native libraries and avoid this error message.

Answer (score 12):

I tried to pass the command which contains path for **opencv** but I found no other way. Somehow i tried something which created my jar and it is properly running. I copied the opencv_java300.dll file and put it in the directory which is next to the my jar file and did same for all supporting files. 
I used following code to do so.

```
String opencvpath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\files\\";
String libPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
System.load(opencvpath + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME + ".dll");
```

Comment: This was not working correctly for me. I used load() rather than loadLibrary() and prepended the Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME by the path of the DLL file. Finally, the .dll extension is added at the end to form the absolute path of the DLL file. The line I used is "System.load("D:\\OpenCV\\opencv-3.0.0\\opencv\\build\\java\\x64\\"+Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME+".dll");" Remember to use x64 or x86 depending on your system. I did not copied the DLL file.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a command line argument as below and call your class which has the main

```
java -Djava.library.path="Folder which contains your dll" ....
```

Comment: Does this work when creating jar file command prompt...Please tell how can i create jar file including external library ( such as other jar file..opencv-300.jar) with this command.

Comment: This works when executing your class from the prepared jar file. Whenever you are invoking the class in the jar file, you would need  to pass above argument.

Comment: I want to create a runnable jar file which does not take any argument ..Is there any way to give this command in program itself or when creating jar file from command prompt.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible . You can however, write a bat file which inturn calls the runnable jar with the above argument . You can use the bat file instead of the runnable jar.

Comment: It is showing an error    could not find or load main class CrooppingTool2.jar

Comment: What are you trying to invoke and can you provide the class name and package of your main calls ?

Comment: I run this command    java -Djava.library.path="D:\myFolder\" myProject.jar. it shows an error could not find or load main class. But shows no opencv_java300 in java.library.path when run jar from command prompt in usual way. java -jar myProject.jar

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved it by switching the JRE System library. It seems like the problem occurs only if using jre1.8.0_65. Everything worked well by me with jre1.8.0_25, jre1.8.0.45 and jre1.8.0.66

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem when I've configured native library in eclipse.
You need choose a library reference your OS platform.

Look at here: [adding openCV to java buildpath in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316381/adding-opencv-to-java-buildpath-in-eclipse).

Comment: It's not about eclipse, it's about running executable jar

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by removing my `System.loadLibrary("opencv_java300");` From the code and adding the jar file to the classpath in my build.xml:

```
<jar destfile="program.jar" basedir="build/classes">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.src.program"/>
        <attribute name="Class-path" value="opencv-300.jar"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```