# Expoting OpenCV+Java project to jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, export

Can anybody explain how to export my Java project with OpenCV - 2.4.9 to single jar file?
I'm just doing everything, as mentioned in this title: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html#java-eclipse
I've exported my project to disk and then, when i want to run it, nothing happens...
I made Export->Runnable JAR file->(Flag Package required libraries)->Finish
P.S. I have read also [how to make runnable jar for javaCV or openCV project from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108222/how-to-make-runnable-jar-for-javacv-or-opencv-project-from-eclipse/19202226#19202226)
and this [How to package opencv +java in a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269570/how-to-package-opencv-java-in-a-jar)

Answer (score 0):

[how to make runnable jar for javaCV or openCV project from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108222/how-to-make-runnable-jar-for-javacv-or-opencv-project-from-eclipse/19202226#19202226) is a working method to create runnable jars but the problem is Opencv has to be installed in your target machine.Just including the OpenCV jar doesnt do the trick .The target system has to have the OpenCV .dll or .so file in the system.