# How to place only actually needed files of OpenCV library to my app folder to make portable java application (Executable Jar)?

Tags: java, opencv, executable-jar, javacv

I have almost the same situation as in this question: [Trying to make java application (Executable Jar) that uses OpenCV portable. Getting unsatisfied link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269517/trying-to-make-java-application-executable-jar-that-uses-opencv-portable-gett). And this question and questions linked and related to this one helps me to understand more. But I still need help with my problem. My question actually splits onto two interrelated questions:

1. How to determine files of opencv library actually needed for my application (just to grab video)

   On my development computer there is a number of directories with obviously the same collection of dll files of opencv2.4.2 (as i understand only dll files needed):

   - opencv/build/x86/mingw
   - opencv/build/x86/vc9
   - opencv/build/x86/vc10
   - opencv/build/x64/mingw
   - opencv/build/x64/vc9
   - opencv/build/x64/vc10

   I understand division onto x86 and x64, but what about mingw/vc9/vc10?
2. How to organize them to my portable build?

   When i'm creating runnable jar from my project, i have nice option "**Copy required libraries into sub-folder next to the generated JAR**". The folder usually has name of form "**_myApp__lib**". Suppose I placed required dll files to that sub-folder as well. How to make my runnable jar see them? And can i do this without -Djava.library.path? And is it possible to place dll files to separate jar?

Comment: Actually, all files in .../mingw folders except _opencv_ffmpeg242.dll_ has _lib_ prefix in their names and has not _opencv_libname242d.dll_ versions of _opencv_libname242.dll_ files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Related to part 1 of the question:**

As i found out, *mingw*, *vc9* and *vc10* are different c++ compilers used to create corresponding builds, but i still doesn't know what will be changed if i would use *mingw* or *vc9*. I just chose *vc10* as more familiar and fresh. Any explanations here will be appreciated.

But these files is not all files needed! There is **opencv/build/common/tbb** folder where you will find **ia32** (x86 version, as i understand) and **intel64** (x64 version as well) folders which in turn divided by compiler subfolders. So i chose *vc10* again.

Some of dll files, for example for object detection, obviously does not required in my project, but i decided to leave them all. After all they take only 42Mb insteed of about 2,5Gb of whole unpacked openvc library.

**Now about part 2 of the question**

As suggested in many question answers (see [Trying to make java application (Executable Jar) that uses OpenCV portable. Getting unsatisfied link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269517/trying-to-make-java-application-executable-jar-that-uses-opencv-portable-gett) and [adding openCV to java buildpath in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316381/adding-opencv-to-java-buildpath-in-eclipse?lq=1) and linked questions), you may setup *path* windows environment variable or use java comand line *-Djava.library.path* switch to help your application find those dll files or place them to one of the folders in *path* windows environment variable. You even can place whole library to the root of the C: drive.

But there is better decision! You can change Java System property ***java.library.path*** at any moment while your application running using this trick:

```
public static void setLibPath(String path){
    System.setProperty( "java.library.path", path );

    Field fieldSysPath;
    try {
        fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
        fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
        fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

An idea was taken from this [page](http://blog.cedarsoft.com/2010/11/setting-java-library-path-programmatically/) and you may find similar trick [here](http://nicklothian.com/blog/2008/11/19/modify-javalibrarypath-at-runtime/).

With this code snippet you may place all dlls to the **your_opencv_subfolder** subfolder of your app's runnable jar folder and then do something like

```
setLibPath(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\your_opencv_subfolder")
```

before any use of opencv library.